# XMLGregorianCalendar format date in ZonedDateTime

Tags: datetime, java-8, timezone, zoneddatetime

I have a function which takes Date and gives XMLGregorianCalendar formatted date as below which returns date as `2017-11-30T00:00:00.000-08:00` when date provided as `2017-11-30`

```
public static String xmlDate(Date date) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
    if (date != null) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
        gc.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
        gc.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        try {
            xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            //exception
        }
    }
    return xmlDate.toString();
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite above function with Java 8 ZonedDateTime but getting date as `2017-11-29T00:00:00-08:00` .How can I get the exact output same as the above function? Also I dont understand why the date is 29 instead of 30.

```
public static String zonedDatetime(Date date) {
    return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
}
```

Comment: So for the format, am I right in saying that all you consider "wrong" is that it's not including the milliseconds? Any reason you don't just use a custom `DateTimeFormatter`? For the date part, we'd need to know what the value of `date` is... but it would be much better to do one of these at a time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I went for custom DateTimeFormatter to get the milliseconds as well. Please see my comment to the answer by Joe C. Thanks for your time.

Comment: FYI… Your output string of `2017-11-30T00:00:00.000-08:00` is actually in standard format defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), as is the date-only string `2017-11-30`. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: You may want to check once more whether milliseconds are required also when they are `.000`. If I have understood the ISO 8601 format correctly, they are optional.

Comment: @BasilBourque But unless i use this formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")`, java.time classes arent giving output in the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes it is optional. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @jusermar10 The `toString` methods in java.time generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format. `LocalDate.now().toString()` and `OffsetDateTime.now().toString()` and `ZonedDateTime.now().toString()`. The last one uses an extension of standard format, wisely appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

Comment: So summing up, I gather that the output you get from using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is good enough. You don’t need the exact same output as the one you got from `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `date` is this instant, then the reason you are getting the 29th is because that is the date in Los Angeles at this moment (22:53 PST).

If you want to match the local date, then you're probably after something like this:

```
return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Ok. I get it. Is it possible to have the milliseconds as well?

Comment: If you want milliseconds, then why are you truncating it to days?  That just makes no sense...  (But yes, other formatters are available)

Comment: It was not giving milliseconds even If I dont truncate. Anyways, I got the format by using custome formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")` . Thanks for your time.

Comment: In that case, if you found this answer helpful, please do not forget to upvote and accept this answer.